# Issues while installing Windows 10 Pro on asus x99-e ws with raid 1 setup

Tags: windows-10, boot, raid

I have this PC im trying to install Windows pro 64bit on this setup but im totally stuck cause of many problems. Here's some specifications:

- Supply - Corsair HX750i
- MB - Asus X99-E WS
- CPU - Intel xeon E5-2630 v4 2.2 GHz
- GC - a small MSI (not really relevant anyway imo)
- Data - 2 ssd Evo 860 with raid 1 and 2 seagate 4To with raid 1
- RAM - 16 Go 2133 Mhz
- Bios - updated 4001

So first I tried to install Windows through PXE ipv4 while it was installing Windows it crashed and gave me a blue screen: **WHEA UNCORRECTABLE ERROR.**

I tried many changes in the bios, etc but with no result.(Note: it worked before I just upgraded by adding the 4To raid 1 and since it was in Win pro 32bit for no reason I was trying to reinstall the whole thing)

List of things I've tried since this situation:

- remove the HDD Raid 1 and install without it
- upgrade bios-reset bios settings
- change many bios settings recommended for that blue screen error

Then I tried with an USB bootable.

- When booting with legacy I have the error : 0x0000098
- When booting with UEFI I have the error : 0xC000000F

Then I tried to install with a CD and I got only the repair interface available. In the CMD I tried many things like:

```
chkdsk and chkdsk /f

bootrec /fixmbr
```

etc.  and diskpart clean + format to NTFS the whole SSD

When I try to reset option it says that a partition is missing and the repair tool also didn't work. I'm now a bit clueless what I could do to make this work. I really think there's no hardware problem so I come here to ask you if know what could be the solution of all this.

Let me know if you need additional information and thank you for your time.

Comment: For UEFI systems and any Windows 8 or newer, never try "Legacy/BIOS/CSM", that's the first rule. And anything "fixmbr" is for Legacy/MBR only, obviously. Windows in UEFI mode strictly requires GPT, maybe that is the problem, MBR partitioning? Please check before anything else.

Comment: ty for your answer, the GPT keyword helped me find a new thing to try. I'll do: 
`select disk <disk number>
clean
convert gpt
exit` And see if it works.

Comment: Exactly. Windows is very strict about partitioning, GPT for UEFI and MBR for Legacy. You can't expect to just change modes to make it work without re-doing the whole target drive.

Comment: So apparently my usb media tool got corrupted in the process and it's the reason there was errors, the GPT didn't really change anything but since I reinstalled my USB. I can now boot from it and install from it. The problem goes back to the origin issue where both PXE and USB installation now give me WHEA UNCORRECTABLE ERROR. im totally clueless of what I could do to solve this.

Comment: Yes, that definitely would do it. Glad you spotted the problem.

Comment: Well I still have the issue : WHEA UNCORRECTABLE ERROR